# Locally symmetric left invariant Riemannian metrics on compact semi-simple Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact semi-simple simply-connected Lie group endowed with a left invariant symmetric Riemannian metric. I wonder if the metric must bi-invariant or there are examples which are not bi-invariant.